# is calling getWidth() and getHeight() on android.View expensive?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I have an application that draws Bitmaps and drawing primitives on `android.View` `Canvas`. I call operations `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` on a view and/or its `Canvas` a couple of dozen times per frame and the view size can sometimes change.

What are the factors that could make these operations expensive?

Please refrain from answers like "did you profile it?" etc.

Comment: it's a getter. Getters return immediately the private member they are suppose to return

Comment: _Fighting the urge to ask_ "did you profile it" :)

Comment: just override onSizeChanged and you will always be up to date with the size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually getWidth() and getHeight() methods from View just only returns private members value from the class so, it doesn't do any **major operation** internally so, you are safe to use these methods..

```
 public final int getWidth() {
        return mRight - mLeft;
 }

 public final int getHeight() {
        return mBottom - mTop;
 }
```

For more detail about what can be internally going in this class.. take reference from here..

[View Class Reference](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-0/android/view/View.java#View.getWidth%28%29)

Comment: `it doesn't do any operation` ... if a **subtraction** is not to be considered an `operation`!